# Google Calendar API + email notification ics file

Tags: google-calendar-api, icalendar

I'm creating events on google calendar using the Google Calendar API, which is working fine.
When I modify one of those events within Google Calendar, Google can email me an even update with an .ics file.

Is there a way determine the eventid via the email or ics file, and tie it back to the eventid when i created the event using the API?

For example, I want to automatically receive event change emails sent from Google Calendar, and update the event in my database (where I store the eventid returned from adding the event using the API)

Answer (score 1):

In the body of the email, you should have:

`<meta itemprop=3D"eventId/googleCalendar" content=3D"[your event id here]"/>`

However, parsing email is not the best way to do this. The preferred method is laid out here: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/sync

If you're needing/wanting a push method, that is laid out here: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push