# Update attendees when editing a Google calendar event with Google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, icalendar

### Situation

I have a calendar with a lot of events on it (staff appraisals).

I've made a load of modifications (changing the length of the event etc.) but the invitations are going to people who have a lotus notes calendar (poor people).

This means that unless I trigger what would be called "Send notification?" in the click-with-your-mouse version of things, they have no way of knowing that the event has been updated.

([Similar Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10846750/google-calendar-api-email-notification-ics-file))

[image: example of the update triggering]

In this example, the event I'm trying to trigger is the same one as is triggered when the *Send Update?* modal is accepted with *send*.

### Code

Here's some example code that gets all the events on the `Appraisals` calendar and changes their location to 'the moon'.

```
function fixInvitations(){
  //get the callendar named "Appraisals"
  var cApp = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName("Appraisals")[0];
  var events = cApp.getEvents(new Date(), new Date("Dec 30 2014"));

  for (eIndex in events){
    var event = events[eIndex];
    event.setLocation("the moon");
  }
}
```

### Question

How do I trigger an update to all parties invited to an event so that the changes are reflected in their calendars?

Currently these events are now on the moon, but the update hasn't told people who are on non-Google calendars about the change.

### Helpful, but not that helpful fact

The update email that manually triggering sends contains a `.ics` file ([Gist of the contents](https://gist.github.com/notionparallax/9500649)).  This contains a VCALENDAR and a VEVENT. From the [Wikipedia page on VEVENTs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar#Events_.28VEVENT.29)

> For sending an UPDATE for an event the UID should match the original UID. the other component property to be set is:
>
> `SEQUENCE:<Num of Update>`
>
> I.e., for the first update:
>
> `SEQUENCE:1`

So if there was a way to manually build an email with a `.ics` attachment it would solve the problem, but that feels like massive overkill. [This is mentioned here](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=574) but not resolved.

Comment: Can you provide some code to show what you're currently working with?

Comment: I've added some example code.

Comment: I have an idea about linking the calendar to a spreadsheet (importing calendar events to a spreadsheet), and then using a script to duplicate an event, but change a property (in this case, location to the moon), and send an email to all participants that the event details have changed.  I think that would be fairly easy to do.  From my research, sending an email blast to attendees may not be built-in functionality, but it may be possible to do an "end-around" to get to the same destination.

Comment: Using the 'getX' methods to find out about an event is pretty straight forward, I could then send an email to everyone about how the event has changed, but it isn't an *update* to an existing event. If I do that then they have an incorrect event in their calendar, I could make a new event from the values too, but that would result in duplication. When you manually change an event it triggers a "send update email" event of some sort; I want to trigger than from my code.

Comment: another solution would be to .getGuests from the original event, pass that array on to a function with MailApp methods to send an email to all guests letting them know the details have changed.  I may try to put that together as an alternative tomorrow night.  I don't think there's a way to trigger the notification from a script.  I read all of the relevant class documentation and didn't see anything.

I added my answer, which still needs some modifications to fix the createNewEvent that I broke with the onEdit event, so if you want to wait to accept the answer until I fix that, I understand.

Answer (score 2):

The Google Calendar API supports the flag sendNotifications for event updates:
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/update

I would file a feature request for App Script to expose the flag and in the meantime use the Calendar API directly for updating events just like an external API:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/external

Comment: Feature request: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3785

Answer (score 2):

I was struggling with this one a bit and got some help from ekoleda+devrel@google.com: Ability for Calendar to send email invitation to users added via addGuest http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=574

A couple of pointers to hopefully save people some time:

> Note that CalendarApp and the Advanced Calendar service use different
>   event ID formats:
>
> > - CalendarApp returns event IDs with "@google.com" at the end ex. b3gv...a5jrs@google.com
> > - The Advanced Calendar service/Calendar API expects an event ID that does not have @google.com ex. b3gv...a5jrs

Here's some working code:

```
function sendInvite(calendarId, eventId, email) {
  var event = Calendar.Events.get(calendarId, eventId);
  if(event.attendees) {
    event.attendees.push({
      email: email
    });
  } else {
    event.attendees = new Array({email: email});
  }
  event = Calendar.Events.patch(event, calendarId, eventId, {
    sendNotifications: true
  });
}
```

One final note for those following along - you won't receive an email notification if you're the event owner and you're trying to add your own email address.  This makes sense in the calendar world since you wouldn't go into your own calendar event, add yourself as an attendee, and expect to be prompted as to whether or not you want to inform yourself.   However, it's probably a common way for people to try and test things (I don't have a domain test account and I can't always reliably test things with my personal gmail account).  So if you're testing with your own account and thinking that things aren't working please keep this in mind.   Once you try things with a non-event owner account the invite will be sent via email.

Answer (score 1):

I think one solution is to create a spreadsheet with the column headers: Event ID, Event Name, Description, Start Time, End Time, Location,Guest List, and then add this script to the spreadsheet.  calendarImport() will import all of your calendar events and write them to the sheet.  Then, you can modify the event in the spreadsheet line (change location to the Moon), and run calendarCreateEvent to create a new event based on the changes you made.  It will automatically send out notifications to all old attendees to accept the new event, as it is a new invitation.

I am pretty close to that solution, but I have a hangup, now, on accessing the calendar to create a new event.  I think it's because I'm calling it from an onEdit event function.  It's getting late, but if you rewrite the third part of the script to get the events data range, then a for/if loop to check the added versus modified date, then you should be able to create a new event, and delete the old event.  This would push a notification of the change in event details to everyone who had accepted the old event already.

I think, given the code example you put up in the beginning, you probably already know how to do that, but if you don't, I could probably throw something together tomorrow night to search for old events that have been recreated and delete them.

[Here's my spreadsheet and code in action.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Amp9JhtmHqC8dFBfLXJDNXlpbDBOU2VnM2dBcFV6Q1E#gid=0)

```
function calendarImport(){
  //http://www.google.com/google-d-s/scripts/class_calendar.html#getEvents
  // The code below will retrieve events between 2 dates for the user's default calendar and
  // display the events the current spreadsheet
  var cal = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();
  var calId = cal.getId();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var sheetName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().setName(calId +" Calendar Data");
  var events = cal.getEvents(new Date("March 9, 2014"), new Date("March 14, 2014"));
  for (var i=0;i<events.length;i++) {
    //http://www.google.com/google-d-s/scripts/class_calendarevent.html
    Logger.log(events);
    var details=[[events[i].getId(),events[i].getTitle(), events[i].getDescription(), events[i].getStartTime(), events[i].getEndTime(),events[i].getLocation()]];
    var guestList = events[i].getGuestList();
    var guestArray = [];
    for (var n in guestList){
      var guestEmail = (guestList[n].getEmail());
      guestArray.push(guestEmail);
      Logger.log(guestArray);

    }

    var row=i+1;
    var range=sheet.getRange(row+1,1,1,6);
    range.setValues(details);
    var guestRange = sheet.getRange(row+1,7,1,1);
    guestRange.setValues([guestArray]);
    var dateAdded = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-6","MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss");
    var dateAddedRange = sheet.getRange(row+1,8,1,1);
    dateAddedRange.setValue(dateAdded);
  }
}

function onEdit(event){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var calId = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().getId();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var actSht = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var actRng = event.source.getActiveRange();
  var index = actRng.getRowIndex();
  Logger.log(index);
  var dateCol = actSht.getLastColumn();
  var calId
  var lastCell = actSht.getRange(index,dateCol);
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-6", "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
  lastCell.setValue(date);
  var modifiedRow = sh.getRange(index,1,1,ss.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  Logger.log(modifiedRow[0][7])
  if (modifiedRow[0][7] < modifiedRow[0][8]){
    var firstAdded = modifiedRow[0][7];
    var dateModified = modifiedRow[0][8];
    calendarCreateEvent(index,firstAdded,dateModified,calId);
  }


}

function calendarCreateEvent(index,firstAdded,dateModified,calId){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var added = firstAdded;
  var modified = dateModified;
  var startRow = index;  // First row of data to process
  var calId = calId;
  Logger.log(calId);
  Logger.log(startRow);
  Logger.log(added);
  Logger.log(modified);
  if (modified - added > "0"){
    var numRows = 1;   // Number of rows to process
    var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 9);
    var data = dataRange.getValues();
    var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calId);
    for (i in data) {
      var row = data[i];
      var eventId = row[0]
      var title = row[1];  // First column
      var desc = row[2];       // Second column
      var tstart = row[3];
      var tstop = row[4];
      var loc = row[5];
      var guests = row[6];
      //cal.createEvent(title, new Date("March 3, 2010 08:00:00"), new Date("March 3, 2010 09:00:00"), {description:desc,location:loc});
      var newEvent = cal.createEvent(title, tstart, tstop, {description:desc,location:loc, guests:guests});//.addGuest(guests);
      var newEventId = newEvent.getId();
      Logger.log(newEventId);

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That's pretty cool! Although it doesn't solve my problem of wanting to update existing events. If I were to do this it would litter people's calendars with events that are no longer real. I guess I could take the event's details, delete it and recreate it with the new properties, but there's no guarantee that it'll actually send an update about the deleted event.

Comment: Actually, that was my plan, I just haven't had time to finish it.  If you'll notice, I added the event ID to tracking, so once you create the new event, you can go back and delete the old event with another function.  Also, I broke my code trying to do some more complex actions with it, so don't go to the test site anymore, it's busted.  According to my research, you can't trigger the send notification with a script (no method for it).  The other option is to modify the event, get the guest list, and send an update using MailApp to notify guests that event details changed (probably easier).

Comment: If you create a new event after editing, it automatically pops up on the attendees calendars like a new event (I'd recommend changing the event title or description to indicate that the new event is a modified version of the old event.)  But, you'd create the new event first (with the new properties), and then delete the old, without notifying attendees that the old event had been deleted.  Since it creates a new event with your old guest list (and you can filter out the "not attendings", you can make sure everyone knows the event has changed by monitoring the "Yes" response on the new one.

Comment: ..which works if you are using a Google calendar, but my attendees are all using non-Google calendars. With a Google only solution just updating the event makes it change, but once you go outside you need to trigger updates.

Comment: Do people using other calendars receive invites through email that get added to their calendars automatically? Or do they have to manually add them?  I'm not as familiar with how many calendars work (I think you mentioned Lotus).  If they do, then you can send a notification email when you create the new event as is here in the docs https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#createEvent(String,Date,Date,Object).

Comment: I've been working on a solution that's got stumped again, [Q here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22393988/make-an-email-be-interpreted-as-an-event-by-mail-clients)

@thoughtcrime : yes, it's all done with email, but the option to send an email is *only* available when creating a new event, not updating an old one.

Answer (score 0):

I got an email from Gooogle today saying that they've added a feature to app script that makes this possible.

> Updates:
>           Status: Fixed
>           Owner: ekoleda+devrel@google.com
>           Labels: -Priority-Medium
>
> Comment #11 on issue 574 by ekoleda+devrel@google.com: Ability for Calendar to send email invitation to users added via addGuest
>   http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=574
>
> This is now possible using the Advanced Calendar service:
>
> https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/calendar
>
> You can use Calendar.Events.patch() to add attendees, and if you set the optional parameter sendNotifications to "true" the attendees will get an invite.
>
> https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/patch

I'm going to try to solve this problem today and then edit this response to reflect that.

Comment: This was never updated with the answer. Can you recall if you solved this? :)