# Generating a .ics Meeting Invitation Via Google Sheets

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I'm putting together a sidebar through google sheets API that takes user input which sends indicated recipients a meeting invitation. The user input data is added to a map `eventData` within function `sendEmail()`. When I select the button 'Send Email' in my side bar, nothing happens, and I'm struggling to understand why.

Here is a pertinent snippet of my .gs code:

```
function generateICSContent(eventData) {
  var icsContent = 
    "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\n" + 
    "PRODID:-//Your Organization//Your App//EN\n" +
    "VERSION:2.0\n" + 
    "METHOD:REQUEST\n" +
    "BEGIN:VEVENT\n" +
    "UID:" + Utilities.getUuid() + "\n" + 
    "SUMMARY:" + eventData.get("title_subject") + "\n" +
    "DTSTART:" + eventData.get("startDate") + "T" + eventData.get("startTime") + "Z\n" + 
    "DTEND:" + eventData.get("endDate") + "T" + eventData.get("endTime") + "Z\n" + 
    "LOCATION:" + eventData.get("location") + "\n" +
    "DESCRIPTION:" + eventData.get("description") + "\n" + 
    "END:VEVENT\n" + 
    "END:VCALENDAR";

  return icsContent;
}

function sendEmail(eventData) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("Sending email to " + eventData.get("email"));
  var icsContent = generateICSContent(eventData);
  var attachmentBlob = Utilities.newBlob(icsContent, "text/calendar", "meeting.ics");
  MailApp.sendEmail(eventData.get("email"), eventData.get("title_subject"), eventData.get("body"), {
    attachments: [attachmentBlob]
  });
}
```

Here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base target="_top">
</head>
<script>
 function sendEmail() {
    var eventData = new Map();

    eventData.set("email", document.getElementById('email').value);
    eventData.set("title_subject", document.getElementById('title_subject').value);
    eventData.set("startDate", document.getElementById('startDate').value);
    eventData.set("endDate", document.getElementById('endDate').value);
    eventData.set("startTime", document.getElementById('startTime').value);
    eventData.set("endTime", document.getElementById('endTime').value);
    eventData.set("location", document.getElementById('location').value);
    eventData.set("body", document.getElementById('body').value);

    google.script.run.sendEmail(eventData);
 }
</script>
<body>
  Emails:
    <input type="text" id="email">
  <br>
  Subject/Meeting Title:
    <input type="text" id="title_subject">
  <br>
  Meeting Start Date:
    <input type="text" id="startDate">
  <br>
  Meeting End Date:
    <input type="text" id="endDate">
  <br>
  Meeting Start Time:
    <input type="text" id="startTime">
  <br>
  Meeting End Time:
    <input type="text" id="endTime">
  <br>
  Meeting Location:
    <input type="text" id="location">
  <br>
  Description:
    <input type="text" id="body">
  <br>
    <input type="button" class="button" value="Send Email" onclick="sendEmail();">
</body>
</html>
```

UPDATE: I have my sidebar widget working nicely now. It creates a .ics attachment that can be sent to indicated recipients with the option to include a zoom meeting ID. It also populates title and description info based on the active cell and the surrounding contents separated by a blank row. Here is a link to an example sheet for anyone interested:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gQ_9xGudV2YboTmytJcDbOPBHb9dUUlRJPjpioF1oJQ/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

Comment: Try adding Logger.log(eventData) in the row after the function declaration in the sendEmail function in google apps script.  You called the first section of code Javascript but I presume that you meant it to be google apps script because Javascript knows nothing about SpreadsheetApp.  Let's determine where the code is failing let me know what you get.

Comment: So based on your recent edits, if the toast doesn't go in, yes it is not executing. I just want to confirm that it is your whole code right?

Comment: By the way I wanted to confirm if you have checked this post as well? 

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22393988/make-an-email-be-interpreted-as-an-event-by-mail-clients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22393988/make-an-email-be-interpreted-as-an-event-by-mail-clients)

Comment: StartDate and endDate are just text so they are not restricted from passing in google.script.run

Comment: You just need to debug your code and figure what's not working using the debugger.  The debugger won't necessarily find the problems but it will help you to find them.

Comment: @Cooper I edited to .gs rather than javascript. My mistake and thank you for indicating that. Logger.log(eventData) in that location results in a reference error because eventData is not defined. The map eventData is populated in script tags in my html file. Logger.log(eventData) within the 'sendEmail()' function just starts and completes the execution, no info.

Comment: I've debugged a lot of code similar to this and between the debugger, console.log and Logger.log and a lot of persistence you will be able to find the problem.  Just don't give up.

Comment: Can you also include the copy of your  Manifest.json on your post this way the community have better idea on the start of your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I saw your showing script, it seems that the Map object is returned using `google.script.run`. I thought that this might be the reason for your current issue. In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Javascript side:

#### From:

```
google.script.run.sendEmail(eventData);
```

#### To:

```
google.script.run.sendEmail([...eventData]);
```

#### Google Apps Script side:

#### From:

```
function sendEmail(eventData) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("Sending email to " + eventData.get("email"));
```

#### To:

```
function sendEmail(eventData) {
  eventData = new Map(eventData);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("Sending email to " + eventData.get("email"));
```

#### Note:

The modified whole script is as follows.

##### HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base target="_top">
</head>
<script>
function sendEmail() {
    var eventData = new Map();

    eventData.set("email", document.getElementById('email').value);
    eventData.set("title_subject", document.getElementById('title_subject').value);
    eventData.set("startDate", document.getElementById('startDate').value);
    eventData.set("endDate", document.getElementById('endDate').value);
    eventData.set("startTime", document.getElementById('startTime').value);
    eventData.set("endTime", document.getElementById('endTime').value);
    eventData.set("location", document.getElementById('location').value);
    eventData.set("body", document.getElementById('body').value);

    google.script.run.sendEmail([...eventData]);
}
</script>
<body>
  Emails:
    <input type="text" id="email">
  <br>
  Subject/Meeting Title:
    <input type="text" id="title_subject">
  <br>
  Meeting Start Date:
    <input type="text" id="startDate">
  <br>
  Meeting End Date:
    <input type="text" id="endDate">
  <br>
  Meeting Start Time:
    <input type="text" id="startTime">
  <br>
  Meeting End Time:
    <input type="text" id="endTime">
  <br>
  Meeting Location:
    <input type="text" id="location">
  <br>
  Description:
    <input type="text" id="body">
  <br>
    <input type="button" class="button" value="Send Email" onclick="sendEmail();">
</body>
</html>
```

##### Google Apps Script:

```js
function generateICSContent(eventData) {
  var icsContent =
    "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\n" +
    "PRODID:-//Your Organization//Your App//EN\n" +
    "VERSION:2.0\n" +
    "METHOD:REQUEST\n" +
    "BEGIN:VEVENT\n" +
    "UID:" + Utilities.getUuid() + "\n" +
    "SUMMARY:" + eventData.get("title_subject") + "\n" +
    "DTSTART:" + eventData.get("startDate") + "T" + eventData.get("startTime") + "Z\n" +
    "DTEND:" + eventData.get("endDate") + "T" + eventData.get("endTime") + "Z\n" +
    "LOCATION:" + eventData.get("location") + "\n" +
    "DESCRIPTION:" + eventData.get("description") + "\n" +
    "END:VEVENT\n" +
    "END:VCALENDAR";

  return icsContent;
}

function sendEmail(eventData) {
  eventData = new Map(eventData);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("Sending email to " + eventData.get("email"));
  var icsContent = generateICSContent(eventData);
  var attachmentBlob = Utilities.newBlob(icsContent, "text/calendar", "meeting.ics");
  MailApp.sendEmail(eventData.get("email"), eventData.get("title_subject"), eventData.get("body"), {
    attachments: [attachmentBlob]
  });
}
```

#### Reference:

- [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)