# Changing Color on Event in Google Calendar

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

Im trying to use the advanced calendar service in Google Apps Script to change the colorId on a particular event in my calendar.

So far i have been able to **list** and **get** event's and the event i like. So i have the ID of the event.

```
function getSpecificEvent(){
  var calendarId = 'primary';
  var eventId = '7h2tbvns2oo4r5gku6ghjfjclk';
  var calEvent = Calendar.Events.get(calendarId, eventId);
  Logger.log(calEvent);
}
```

This is what im trying when editing the colorID, i use **[patch](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/patch)**:

```
function setEventColor(){
  var calendarId = 'primary';
  var eventId = '7h2tbvns2oo4r5gku6ghjfjclk';
   Calendar.Events.patch(calendarId, eventId).colorId('11');
}
```

But then i get this error:
[image]

Line 33 in this case is this line:

```
   Calendar.Events.patch(calendarId, eventId).colorId
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bit tricky... but I found how it works :

```
function ChangeEventColor(){
  var calendarId = 'primary';
  var eventId = 'omv°°°°°°°°°°8jbs'
  var event = Calendar.Events.get(calendarId, eventId)
  Logger.log('current color = '+event.colorId)
  event.colorId = 11
  Calendar.Events.patch(event,calendarId,eventId);
  Logger.log('new color = '+event.colorId)
}
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22187070/update-attendees-when-editing-a-google-calendar-event-with-google-apps-script/23505177#23505177) (anonymous) was very helpful

Comment: That worked as expected, many thanks Serge as always, and thanks to the post!